# calculate char's bbox with mupdf fz_stext_char_bbox

Tags: c, pdf, transform

I occur an strange phenomenon using mupdf, which when I use fz_stext_char_bbox to get char's bbox, a lot of bbox are correct, but a little are wrong. I draw the bbox with red rectange on screen. Following picture is my capture:
[image]

these wrong bbox are always 0 on lefttop. In my code,

1. I get the `fz_page` by pageNo first.
2. then I use `fz_new_stext_sheet`, `fz_new_stext_page` and `fz_new_stext_device` create necessary parameter.
3. I use `fz_run_page` with current matrix and above parameters.
4. then I following the mupdf to use `fz_stext_char_bbox` in order to get the bbox.

I'm not sure it's necessory to list my code here, becaause it maybe too long. I seems my transform matrix is right but don't know why has wrong bbox. Do I forget something?

Comment: Without seeing the code I can't say for sure, but my guess is that you're not scaling the transform matrix correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I used mupdf-1.8 version and solved it.